# Laggy navigation bar when size changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a navbar with a transition effect when the page is scrolled down using Javascript and Tailwindcss.

It works perfectly, but there is a slight lag in the transition effect (you'll notice it when you scroll back up). This problem also causes sections in main to halt and move. I am sharing my demo code below. You can also access the codepen link [here](https://codepen.io/berkesasa/pen/MWXNmyO) so that you can edit it easily. Thank you in advance for all your support.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $('#header').addClass('sticky');
      $('#header').addClass('top-0');
      $('#header').addClass('shadow-xl');
      $('#navbar').removeClass('pb-8');
      $('#logo').removeClass('shadow-xl');
      $("#header").css({
        'transition': '1s'
      })
      $("#navbar").css({
        'transition': '1s'
      })
      $("#logo").css({
        'transition': '1s'
      })
    } else {
      $('#header').removeClass('shadow-xl');
      $('#header').removeClass('sticky');
      $('#header').removeClass('top-0');
      $('#navbar').addClass('pb-8');
      $('#logo').addClass('shadow-xl');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<header id="header" class="sticky !top-0 !z-50 bg-white">
  <nav id="navbar" class="w-full pb-8 transition-all 2xl:px-5 max-2xl:px-5">
    <div class="container flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center mx-auto xl:space-x-20">
      <a id="logo" class="flex items-center p-5 bg-white rounded-bl-lg rounded-br-lg shadow-xl" href="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/60" class="h-16">
      </a>
      <div class="wd-mobile-dropdown flex items-center justify-center space-x-10 !w-auto">
        <ul class="flex items-center justify-center p-4 mx-auto mt-4 space-x-14 ml-20 ">
          <li class="mx-auto">
            <a href="" class="block px-4 md:p-0">Navbar</a>
          </li>
          <li class="mx-auto">
            <a href="" class="block px-4 md:p-0">Navbar2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="mx-auto">
            <a href="" class="block px-4 md:p-0">Navbar3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="mx-auto">
            <a href="" class="block px-4 md:p-0">Navbar4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <section>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 justify-center items-center gap-10">
      <a href="#" class="block mx-auto max-w-sm p-6 border rounded-lg shadow-md bg-gray-800 border-gray-700">
        <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl text-white">Noteworthy technology acquisitions 2021</h5>
        <p class="text-white">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block mx-auto max-w-sm p-6 border rounded-lg shadow-md bg-gray-800 border-gray-700">
        <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl text-white">Noteworthy technology acquisitions 2021</h5>
        <p class="text-white">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block mx-auto max-w-sm p-6 border rounded-lg shadow-md bg-gray-800 border-gray-700">
        <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl text-white">Noteworthy technology acquisitions 2021</h5>
        <p class="text-white">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block mx-auto max-w-sm p-6 border rounded-lg shadow-md bg-gray-800 border-gray-700">
        <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl text-white">Noteworthy technology acquisitions 2021</h5>
        <p class="text-white">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block mx-auto max-w-sm p-6 border rounded-lg shadow-md bg-gray-800 border-gray-700">
        <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl text-white">Noteworthy technology acquisitions 2021</h5>
        <p class="text-white">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block mx-auto max-w-sm p-6 border rounded-lg shadow-md bg-gray-800 border-gray-700">
        <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl text-white">Noteworthy technology acquisitions 2021</h5>
        <p class="text-white">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block mx-auto max-w-sm p-6 border rounded-lg shadow-md bg-gray-800 border-gray-700">
        <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl text-white">Noteworthy technology acquisitions 2021</h5>
        <p class="text-white">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block mx-auto max-w-sm p-6 border rounded-lg shadow-md bg-gray-800 border-gray-700">
        <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl text-white">Noteworthy technology acquisitions 2021</h5>
        <p class="text-white">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks to me that the 1s are kumulative so you get 3 secs to do the complete transition. Change the 3 times 1s to for example .1s .2s and .3s

Comment: The transition times you're describing are times with different ids. I still tried, but something hasn't changed, unfortunately.